# Which button to highlight: Checkout or Continue shopping button

Tags: e-commerce, information-architecture

Type of website: Apparel online store

Here is my question, once I am a on product page and click on the add to cart I have 2 single choices: Continue my shopping or Check-out.

What is the best option to highlight or not ? What is depending-on?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I think this highly depends on the sort of product you're selling. For example, you're not very likely to buy more than one product in a computer store. If, one the other hand, you're an online supermarket, i would recommend 'Continue shopping'. However, if the preferred option is 'continue shopping', you should think about why you want to show the message anyway. Maybe there is a more elegant way, like putting the basket in one of the corners and let it highlight the moment you add a product to it. This way the shop experience isn't disturbed.

Comment: Exactly - Call To Action buttons are made to help users decide on where to click. Hence, the Call To Action button should be the one you want your users (in most cases) to click. And what button that should be is something for you as an UX/Interaction Designer to figure out...